# How to segment visitors who viewed at least 3 product pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a Google Analytics segment that identifies engaged users defined as visitors who view at least 10 or more product pages (so only pages that contact the URI /product)
Ideally I could do this within a session (users who visited 10 product pages within a session) and across session (users who visited 10 product pages over any number of sessions) - so Session and User based segments.
But I am not clear how to limit this to product pages.
I don't think this works:  Pageviews per session ≥ 10 AND Page contains /product.  I think that just gives me any session with pageviews>10 and at least one page was a product page.
Anyone understand the mystery of Google Analytics Considitonal segments?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom sequence segment for this
**Filter** > *Include* > *Sessions*  **Sequence start** > *Any user interaction*
Segment contains 10 steps.
Each step configured as Page contains /product
followed by
This way the segment will only include those that visited 10 product pages throughout their session.
Can also create another one configured for User
[image]

Comment: If someone visits a product page and then performs 9 actions on that page that are tracked as events, this segment will catch them as well. (Which might be okay, they're clearly very engaged...)